# Mysql Query Null Value is not including in where condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have written this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `venue_event` 
WHERE  
owner_account_id=3 and venue_id=1 and status !=  'paid'
```

I have 1 row in table

like this

```
    venue_id    owner_account_id   status

     1             3                  NULL
```

Status may have NULL,terms_accepted,cancel or paid values in one row.(Means it can't have duplicate values for same venue and owner_account_id).
when status equal to NULL its not giving any result.i want this row in result whenever status not equal to paid.
what i should change..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like

```
SELECT * FROM venue_event 
WHERE
owner_account_id=3 AND venue_id=1 AND
(status != 'paid' OR status IS NULL)
```

Comment: Shouldn't be status IS NULL?

Comment: Sorry I forgot...Either the way we can use.Anyway thanks @Mihai

Comment: i have also tried this but not worked SELECT * FROM venue_event WHERE owner_account_id=3 and venue_id=1 and (status != 'paid' or status is null)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this query

```
SELECT * FROM venue_event WHERE
owner_account_id=3 and venue_id=1 AND status <>  'paid' OR status IS NULL
```

Comment: Should be `OR` instead of `AND`

Comment: i have also tried this but not worked

SELECT * 
FROM  `venue_event` 
WHERE  
owner_account_id=3 and venue_id=1 and (status !=  'paid' or status is null)

Comment: That was not my query.

Comment: Can you try this ? `SELECT * FROM venue_event WHERE
owner_account_id=3 and venue_id=1 AND (status <>  'paid' OR status IS NULL)`